# See if $_POST value matches an Array element value

Tags: php, arrays, forms, for-loop, foreach

I am very new to PHP.  I am writing a "quiz" php form where the first goal is to require that users enter a valid "user account" name.  I already have the lists of user accounts and created an array called $users.  I think I need to put the verification php section above the form.  I have declared the $users array and below it, start with:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

               if (empty($_POST["uName"])) {
                    $uNameErr = "User name is required";
                    } 
                    else {
                         ....do something here
                          )
               }
```

I am not sure if I should use a foreach, for loop, or count through the array and compare the posted uName (username) with values of each element of the $users array. I can't produce the correct echo statements (as a test) with any of those methods.  The last I have tried is:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

               if (empty($_POST["uName"])) {
                    $uNameErr = "User name is required";
                    } 
                    else {

                        foreach($users as $value){

                            if ($value ===($_POST["uName"])){
                                    echo "needle is in the array";
                                } 
                                    else {
                                echo "needle is not in the array";      
                                }
                        }
```

Any help on this is highly welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). This can easily replace your foreach loop. I find that I only use foreach when I need to operate on each value.

In this case you can do

```
if (in_array($_POST['uName'], $users))
echo 'they are in the array';
else echo 'they are not in the array';
```

additionally, you can replace

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

with

```
if (isset($_POST["uName"]){
```